# Internet connectivity lost and Event Log service doesn't work

Tags: windows, networking, connection, repair

My Windows 7 (64-bit) machine lost internet connectivity. Rebooting didn't help. On boot-up systray message would appear:

> Failed to connect to a windows service. Windows could not connect to the System Event 
>   Notification Service service. This problem prevents limited users from logging on to the 
>   system. As an administrative user, you can review the System Event Log for details about why 
>   the service didn't respond.

Event Viewer just showed an error that the 'Event Log service is unavailable'. After trying to start it manually, I got:

> Windows could not start the Windows Event Log service on Local computer.
>   Error 1747: The authentication service is unknown

I have tried running a couple of virus scanners and malware removal programs, and doing the System File Checker command:

```
sfc /scannow
```

but there were no useful results.

Booting into safe-mode didn't make any difference.

System restore showed that there are no restore points, although the System restore was turned on on the machine.

I'd really like to not have to re-install the OS again.

Comment: This may also be a sign of Infection...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more digging on the net I found this [link](http://windows7themes.net/repair-reset-winsock-windows-7.html) detailing the procedure for troubleshooting the network connectivity:

This was the solution to my problem

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Comment: Just used this to fix the same problem on Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I lost Internet connectivity after using several applications to remove some malware called PC Speed Maximizer v3.2. Afterwards, I got a prompt stating:

> tcp/ip protocol is not installed properly

and another:

> initialization function inithelperdll in nshhttp.dll failed to start with error code 10107

I ended up solving the problem by reinstalling the driver software for the wireless adapter. (System stats: Gateway laptop, Windows 7 64-bit.)